# How can I make this Javascript code more Dry?

Tags: javascript, refactoring

This is for one of the assignments on Odin Project. As i'm testing things out, i'm realizing how this code is bad because it's not DRY. I would just be creating more and more book objects.  How can I make this more clean?

```js
let myLibrary = [];

    function Book(title, author, pages, hasRead){
      this.title = title;
      this.author = author; 
      this.page = pages;
      this.hasRead = hasRead;
    };
    
    function addBookToLibrary(newBook){
      return myLibrary.push(newBook)
    };
    
    let newBook = new Book("Wool", "Hugh Howey", "592", false);
    let lifeOfPi = new Book("Life of Pi", "Yann Martel", "392", false);
    
    addBookToLibrary(newBook);
    addBookToLibrary(lifeOfPi);
    console.log(myLibrary);
```

Comment: Accept parameters in your `addBookToLibrary` that has the properties of the "book". Then create and push the object to the array in that function. Alternatively, make a "BookLibrary" class, that has all the needed methods, including the `myLibrary` array.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, so that you have a "BookLibrary" class.

```js
// Make the class "BookLibrary"

var BookLibrary = function() { 

    
    this.myLibrary = [];


    this.addBookToLibrary = function(title, author, page, hasRead) {

        var newBook = {}; // a book new object to be stored to array

        newBook.title = title;
        newBook.author = author;
        newBook.page = page;
        newBook.hasRead = hasRead;

        this.myLibrary.push( newBook ); // add to collection of books

    }
    
}

// test demo

// instantiate the object 
var books = new BookLibrary();

// add some books
books.addBookToLibrary("Wool", "Hugh Howey", "592", false);
books.addBookToLibrary("Life of Pi", "Yann Martel", "392", false);

// see if it worked
console.log( books.myLibrary );
```